# Issue while creating users with profile image in CQ5/AEM

Tags: aem

I am using `AccountManager` API to create users. It works just fine when I don't use profile image in registration form and user gets registered but once I use profile image, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No matching property definition: jcr:primaryType = sling:Folder
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.NodeDelegate.setProperty(NodeDelegate.java:522)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$35.perform(NodeImpl.java:1308)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$35.perform(NodeImpl.java:1297)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:293)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:113)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.internalSetProperty(NodeImpl.java:1297)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.setProperty(NodeImpl.java:340)
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrModifiablePropertyMap.save(JcrModifiablePropertyMap.java:180)
    ... 145 more
```

There is a hidden field to create this folder

```
<hidden
     jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
     sling:resourceSuperType="foundation/components/form/defaults/field"
     sling:resourceType="foundation/components/form/hidden"
     defaultValue="sling:Folder"
     name="photos/jcr:primaryType"/>
```

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

"**sling:Folder**" cannot be used for a jcr node type when using Node.class.

Use "**nt:unstructured**"

I faced a similar issue and this resolved it.

Comment: did you do it for user registration?